# How can I find the actual size of SSAS Partition?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, ssas

The properties window for a partition only shows the **estimated size** of the partition.

[image]

Is there a way to get the actual size of a partition?

**Edit:**

I do not have administrative or remote desktop permissions to the server. While SSAS permissions can be granted, remoting in is not a possibility for me.

Answer (score 4):

The easiest way I can think of would be to check the files on disk. The data for each partition is broken out into it's own folder.

```
..\<Cube>\<MeasureGroup>\<Partition1>
..\<Cube>\<MeasureGroup>\<Partition2>
..
..\<Cube>\<MeasureGroup>\<PartitionN>
```

[image]

You'll probably want to script it using PowerShell if you need to gather this info regularly for more than a few partitions. Also, keep in mind that the partition-level folders include data for aggregations as well (which you may or may not want).

Comment: I should have stated that I don't have admin or remoting permissions to the server.

Comment: perhaps you could build a powershell script (using a Dev instance where you do have admin privileges) and have the DBA execute the script and send you the results.